# I tried client.accept_invite() but It seems like discord doesn't allow that instead it says Guild Add Member should be used

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried client.accept_invite(), but discord API says that 
[Guild Add Member](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member) should be used instead. I don't understand the concept in which Guild Add Member works, any help? How do I use the function same as accept_invite()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't.  `Add Guild Member` allows your bot, which has been added to a server, to give other people access to the server.

The ability to accept invites through the API has been *intentionally removed*. I don't expect the ability to log into the API with a username/password to remain long either.  User automation/self bots (running a bot that uses a user account) is not allowed by Discord, and their API is changing to reflect that.

If you have some other reason for needing this functionality, feel free to ask about that problem in more detail.